# MongoDB Shard key Selection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I've a scenario in which I don't know what would be the structure & fields of collections in MongoDb. Also there will be like multiple single DB per user(Like Multi-tenant DB).

I'll be deploying Replicated sharded cluster in production.For scaling & better machine optimization, I'm applying sharding on per DB basis during the creation of each DB, and each collection under the same DB will be sharded to different shards. Now in this scenario I'm not sure which key would be the best choice since the structure & field(s) of collection(s) which would be created under each DB will be unknown. Since the structure of DB, Collection is unknown I can't forecast which type of query will be used most of the time. So I want to select a shard key which would fulfill all the criteria for shard key selection like: Cardinality, Query Isolation, Monotonically increasing, Write scaling, Easily divisible.

What would be the solution in this scenario?

Also What if I select all the fields under that collection for shard key along with hashed _id field as compound key?

Answer (score 0):

Once you create a shard key you can not edit it.
So keep pumping the data into the collection, once you get clarity on the fields you can shard the collections any time.

Rebalancing happens automatically after sharding.